# How to fetch videos by geolocation with the Youtube API v3?

Tags: geolocation, youtube-api

This maps api answer says

> Please note you can also use the YouTube API to fetch geolocated
>   videos to create your own customized YouTube Layer, with filters and
>   so forth.

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3204#c9

Which API request can be used to fetch videos by location? I checked the docs, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#locationsp is what you were talking about, note how it says "Not working. This API parameter is temporarily disabled. See the API issue tracker for more information."

 Edit: According to https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4234 it will be fixed "In the second half of 2013"

Comment: The problem is a member of an other google team says in the quoted part there is no problem shutting down a feature, because the youtube api supports this feature, but if it's not supported at the moment and the other feature is shut down then sites using that feature will stop working due to a lack of migration path.

Comment: According to the bug tracker it should be up in "The second half of 2013" which, knowing dev teams, means the first half of 2014, so I'd expect a fix withing a few months. Here's the tracker if you're interested: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4234

Comment: Okay, but the maps api v2 is shut down on the 19th of this month, so there should be a solution by then, otherwise sites using this feature of the maps v2 api cannot migrate to maps api v3 + youtube api if it's not fixed by the 19th.